# MYSQL Show only Subquery COUNT

Tags: mysql, sql, count, subquery

I have to join a subquery to the main query. I have got a problem with retrieving data of a count function of subquery.

Below you can find the subquery and the result of the count function is **3**:

```
SELECT
            od.id,
            od.number,  
            count(odl.number IN ('APAC')) as "APAC"
        FROM
            order_data od
        left JOIN order_data_line odl 
        ON odl.id_no = od.id
```

RESULT:

```
od.id od.number APAC
123      123      1
```

but when I will add it to the main query, the result is **9**

```
SELECT
    od.number,
    q.APAC
FROM
    order_data od
           LEFT JOIN  
       (SELECT
            od.id,
            order.number,  
            count(odl.number IN ('APAC')) as "APAC"
        FROM
            order_data od
        left JOIN order_data_line odl 
        ON odl.id_no = od.id) q 
ON q.id = od.id
  GROUP BY 
od.number
```

RESULT:

```
 od.number q.APAC
    123      15
```

I want to get the  q.APAC result the same i got from the subquery = **3**. In other words, full query should show me the result of q.APAC = **3** =

```
 od.number q.APAC
    123      3
```

I thought SELECT will show me only the COUNT function result of the subquery, but it sum's up results from the main query. I do not know how should I do that, I tried DISTINCT in many places, but it did not solve the problem.

Thank you in advance for helping me

Comment: Provide the data for the tables and expected result

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. There is no **IN** in the COUNT.
Solution is
`Sum(CASE  when odl.number = "APAC" then 1 else null END) as "APAC"`